# VBA automatically hide/unhide rows depending on content row above

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to automatically hide/unhide rows, depending on the content of the row above?

E.g. I have 10 rows. The first two rows should always be visible. If there is no content in the first row, Rows 3-10 are hidden. If there is content (anything) in row 1, row 3 will be unhidden; if there is content in row 2, row 4 will be unhidden and so forth, until all 10 rows are unhidden.

Below these 10 rows, there will be 10 more rows that should be hidden/unhidden accordingly.

Is there a way to realize this with VBA?

Kind regards,

Dennis

Comment: Please see [ask]. The idea is that you tell us what you want to do, what you have tried (including some code), and what results you get. Show some research. For example, if this is not relevant, tell us why: https://superuser.com/q/663441 But know that no one is going to write this code for you.

Comment: What if there is nothing in row 1, but something in row 3?  Row 1 being blank hides rows 3 - 10, but row 3 having something unhides row 4 leave row 3 and 5:10 hidden?

Comment: Also, if row 9 has values then row 11 is unhidden, but row 11 is the start of the next 10 rows....

Comment: Regarding your first problem, I "solved this by including the previous rows in the rows to be unhidden. E.g for row 2:  
`ActiveSheet.Rows("3:4").RowHeight = 15`  

Regarding your second problem: 
I worked around this by just leaving out the rows I do not want to have unhidden. Since you have to list the rows you want to hide manually anyways, it's straightforward. Or are you not referring to Harassed Dad's answer at all?

Comment: No, I wasn't referring to @HarrassedDads answer (include the @ so he gets a notification).  I was asking for clarification to your question as I was preparing my own answer that doesn't include lots of IF statements but is relevant to the row you're updating - i.e. rather than checking if you changed row 1, row 11, row 21 at the top of each block of 10 rows it will perform a calculation on the row number.... I'll add as an "almost complete" answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The trick is to attach your code to the WorkSheet.Change event of the worksheet module page. This will then run everytime someone changes any value in the worksheet. Then it's just a case of a series of IF statements, using the worksheetfunction COUNTA()  to see if there is any data in a particular row and then set the rowhight of your desired row to either zero (to hide it) or back to whatever value is normal for that row

So for example

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Rows("3:10").RowHeight = 0 'hide everything to start
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows("1:1")) > 0 Then 'if anything in row 1
    ActiveSheet.Rows(3).RowHeight = 15  'assuming your sheet has rows set to 15
    End If


End Sub
```

Just repeat the if statements for each row

Comment: I am pretty much a VBA beginner. Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Regarding your example:
Thanks, that works! Repeating the if statement for each row is a bit cumbersome but I really don't want to complain, since it works exactly as I wanted it to. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This code applies to any row you may change.  I understand it may not be a complete answer as I'm not sure what you want to happen when different rows are updated.

It does show how to use Target to examine what you've just changed and to Hide the row rather than change the row height - if you hide a row that is double height, it will set it back to double height when you unhide it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Target is the cell you just changed.
    'Target.Row is the row number you just updated.
    'divide by 10 and look at the remainder - if it's 1 then you're on a multiple of 10 rows.
    'So this bit will fire on row 1, 11, 21, etc accounting for each block of 10 rows.
    If Target.Row Mod 10 = 1 Then

        'Counts the number of cells in the range that are not empty.
        'The range is the entire row of cells on the row you just changed.
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Target.EntireRow) = 0 Then

            'Offset(2) references the cell 2 below Target.
            'Resize(8) changes the range reference to 8 rows and includes the EntireRow
            'which it then hides (so update row 1 and it hides rows 3:10,
            'update row 11 and it hides 12:20.
            Target.Offset(2).Resize(8).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If

    'Now check if the row you just updated is still empty.
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Target.EntireRow) > 0 Then

        'If it's not then reference two rows down and hide that row.
        Target.Offset(2).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

End Sub
```

**Edit:**
This second set of code will look at the top row in your set of 10 and then each of the rows from 3 to 10 beneath it.
e.g. if you update row 17 it will check row 11 and then rows 13 to 20.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim x As Long
    Dim lStartRow As Long, lEndRow As Long

    lStartRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Target.Row, 10) + 1
    lEndRow = lStartRow + 9

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells(lStartRow, 1)) = 0 Then
        Cells(lStartRow, 1).Offset(2).Resize(8).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    For x = lStartRow + 2 To lEndRow

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells(x, 1).EntireRow) > 0 Then
            Cells(x, 1).Offset(2).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If

    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. I like your idea of automating the procedeure instead of relying on numerous if cases.  
Regarding your first code:  
The default initial situation is supposed to be that the rows 3-10 are hidden. Using your code, these lines only get hidden, when I actively delete the content in the first row. Furthermore, if add something to the rows and then delete it again, I get a runtime error 1004, which points to the code `Target.Offset(2).Resize(8).EntireRow.Hidden = True`.

With the second code, the rows get hidden (see code 1) but not unhidden again.

Comment: Only the rows you specified in  your question get unhidden in the second block of code.  For example, if I start with existing values in `A3`, `A5`, `A7` and `A9` and then add a value to `A6`:  row 1 is empty so rows 3:10 are hidden, row 3 has a value so row 5 is unhidden, row 4 doesn't have a value so nothing happens, row 5 unhides row 7, row 6 unhides row 8, row 7 unhides row 9, row 8 is empty, row 9 unhides row 11.  Looking at your question the `+2` in the For loop should be removed as it also checks rows 1 and 2.

Comment: The first block of code doesn't work as expected as I wasn't sure of your requirements which is why I was asking for clarification in the comments.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear, I should have taken more time to elaborate my question.
In general, every row that contains content should be visible. And I always start filling in the rows in each block from the top so the case in your comment (row 2 content, row 1 empty / existing value in A3, A5, A7 and A9 without value in A1-2) wouldn't really apply. The code is supposed to clean up the space a bit and only show me more rows in one block in case I really need them. Without the +2 it works fine. Is there a way to change the block size to something else but 10 and with room between two blocks?

Comment: Yes, if you wanted the 15 row blocks  you'd change the `Floor` in `lStartRow` to `15` and `+14` in the `lEndRow`.  If you wanted to leave two empty rows at the end  you'd change the loop to ignore the last two rows:  `For x = lStartRow To lEndRow - 2`

Comment: Thanks, I only had to also modify the Resize accordingly.